# Search/Filter Dropdown close anywhere

Tags: javascript, html, css

I got this dropdown from w3school but the dropdown closes only when you click on button again. How to make it close by clicking anywhere except search and dropdown.

```js
/* When the user clicks on the button,
toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

function filterFunction() {
    var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
    input = document.getElementById("myInput");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    div = document.getElementById("myDropdown");
    a = div.getElementsByTagName("a");
    for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        if (a[i].innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            a[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
            a[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
```

```css
.dropbtn {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.dropbtn:hover, .dropbtn:focus {
    background-color: #3e8e41;
}

#myInput {
    border-box: box-sizing;
    background-image: url('searchicon.png');
    background-position: 14px 12px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 14px 20px 12px 45px;
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

#myInput:focus {outline: 3px solid #ddd;}

.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f6f6f6;
    min-width: 230px;
    overflow: auto;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

.dropdown a:hover {background-color: #ddd}

.show {display:block;}
```

```html
<h2>Search/Filter Dropdown</h2>
<p>Click on the button to open the dropdown menu, and use the input field to search for a specific dropdown link.</p>

<div class="dropdown">
<button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search.." id="myInput" onkeyup="filterFunction()">
    <a href="#about">About</a>
    <a href="#base">Base</a>
    <a href="#blog">Blog</a>
    <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
    <a href="#custom">Custom</a>
    <a href="#support">Support</a>
    <a href="#tools">Tools</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

I got this dropdown from w3school but the dropdown closes only when you click on button again. How to make it close by clicking anywhere except search and dropdown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an event listener to the body that removes the "show" class.. you probably want to make sure the target is not the button or the input though...

```
document.body.addEventListener("click", function(e){
  if(!e.target.classList.contains("dropbtn") && e.target.id != "myInput")  document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.remove("show");
});
```

```js
document.body.addEventListener("click", function(e){
  if(!e.target.classList.contains("dropbtn") && e.target.id != "myInput")  document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.remove("show");
});

/* When the user clicks on the button,
toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

function filterFunction() {
    var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
    input = document.getElementById("myInput");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    div = document.getElementById("myDropdown");
    a = div.getElementsByTagName("a");
    for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        if (a[i].innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            a[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
            a[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
```

```css
.dropbtn {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.dropbtn:hover, .dropbtn:focus {
    background-color: #3e8e41;
}

#myInput {
    border-box: box-sizing;
    background-image: url('searchicon.png');
    background-position: 14px 12px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 14px 20px 12px 45px;
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

#myInput:focus {outline: 3px solid #ddd;}

.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f6f6f6;
    min-width: 230px;
    overflow: auto;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

.dropdown a:hover {background-color: #ddd}

.show {display:block;}
```

```html
<h2>Search/Filter Dropdown</h2>
<p>Click on the button to open the dropdown menu, and use the input field to search for a specific dropdown link.</p>

<div class="dropdown">
<button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search.." id="myInput" onkeyup="filterFunction()">
    <a href="#about">About</a>
    <a href="#base">Base</a>
    <a href="#blog">Blog</a>
    <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
    <a href="#custom">Custom</a>
    <a href="#support">Support</a>
    <a href="#tools">Tools</a>
  </div>
</div>
```